# What is the URL format for Google Trends?

Tags: encodings

When you search for the search term Tesla or AOL you get the following URLs:

https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=Tesla

[image]

But, for the automobile maker, you get:

https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=%2Fm%2F0j6n6s8

[image]

So what is the `%2Fm%2F0j6n6s8` part? I know it URL decodes to `/m/0j6n6s8` but how is it being encoded??

One more example of AOL (search term) vs. AOL (company)

https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=AOL
https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=%2Fm%2F0plw

Comment: It may be just id from their database, as it is sent by server when you type your query, this is not generated by client

Comment: It may not be id e.g. for AOL it is a 3 letter `plw` etc.